# VOIP push notification from nodejs server to react native application

Tags: node.js, push-notification, twilio, call, voip

i want to send VOIP push notification using firebase admin using FCM token to my react native app (android and ios both) when incoming twilio call occured on react native application

can you give me nodejs code for send VOIP push notifcation?